# Backward compatibility to old db schema with Linq-To-Sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, schema

We have a software suite with different components and a sql server database that is used by most of these components.

Let's say we have a table `Configuration` with two columns `[Name]`and `[Value]`. This table contains our db scheme version (as `Name='Version', Value='1.0'`).

Then we have a table `Customer` with columns `ID` and `Name`.

So the class for linq-to-sql queries on this table would look something like that:

```
[Table(Name="Customer")]
public class Customer
{
    [Column]
    public long ID {get; private set;}
    [Column]
    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

For our next release version, we need to change this `Customer` table and add a column `Address`. When we install this new scheme, we set the version value in the `Configuration` table to 1.1, so we can determine which version is installed.

A lot of our customers are waiting for this new version of the component because of a bugfix, but they don't actually need the new db schema (the reasons don't matter here, let's just assume **our software needs backward compatibility to old db schema versions**).

So my question is, is there any best practice technology to handle this situation?

If I add the new column to the `Customer` class like

```
[Column]
public string Address {get; set;}
```

I won't be able to use this class for requests to a db with the 1.0 schema (because of the SqlException for the missing column). If I create a new class (derived, or use interfaces or whatsoever), I have to deal with different types for different schema versions. And of course `Table<Customer10>` will never be convertible to `Table<Customer11>` no matter what the inheritance relation between `Customer10` and `Customer11` will be. So until now I did not find a way to encapsulate these problems inside my DataContext derivate in a transparent way:

```
public class MyDataContext : DataContext
{
    public Table<Customer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            // this won't compile, no matter how Customer10 and Customer11 are related
            return version > 10 
                ? GetTable<Customer11>()
                : GetTable<Customer10>();
        }
    }
}
```

I also experimented with [inheritance hierarchies](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.mapping.inheritancemappingattribute) and [discriminators](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.isdiscriminator), but since the version is not a column of `Customer`, this does not seem to work.

I'd like to find a solution where I can use one type per table for different schemas and where removed or added columns would take default values if they are not supported in the installed db scheme.

Comment: No we don't have direct access to the customers' databases. And of course the given example is a massive simplification of the real database schema. The customers install our software via different MSIs. And sometimes there are different maintenance windows for different servers, so we have cases where new software components are already installed and have to work at the customer's site while the db schema is still the old one. As a developer I don't like that, but this compatibility is what is expected from me, so I have to deal with it.

Comment: And users with 1.1 software but 1.0 schema will not have null Addresses but a SqlException. (I added in the question for clarification)

Comment: And your DataContext is not 'hidden' behind factories or repository typed implementation and sending PoCo type DTO objects to the rest of the code?. In that case you could implement the switch on the version there.

Comment: Perhaps a CustomerAdress table is a relatively dirty but easy solution to circumvent the problem

Comment: @Pleun Thanks for the idea. Thought about it. Currently we are using plain SqlComnands, and I'm researching if linq2sql would be an easier and code - saving alternative. But if I had to implement so much factory code, the benefits of linq2sql will be eaten up.

Comment: @Pleun yes, making future changes only by adding complete new tables could be a way, but I think I  cannot rely on that.